# Optimizing webgl (draw) call overhead

Tags: webgl

I'm trying to use the stencil buffer to render cross-sections of 3d models with WebGL. I am also using a library - three.js, which gives me a scene graph and various other abstractions.

Three.js exposes a callback that is called **before** and **after** `gl.drawElements` which I used to make the stencil calls. If I leave the render order to be managed by three, I end up in this situation:

[image: stencil calls]

Which looks pretty redundant:

```
gl.disable(STENCIL_TEST) //disable followed immediately by enable
gl.enable(STENCIL_TEST)

gl.stencilFunc(...) //same call for multiple draw calls
gl.stencilOp(...)
```

It looks like it would require some acrobatics to batch these with three.js, and I'm wondering if it's even worth it. I keep reading about the overhead of WebGL (draw?) calls, but I don't really understand their weight. It's pretty obvious what happens when a bunch of geometry is merged and drawn with a single call, but I don't understand what happens with other calls.

I'm not even entirely sure how to test it, would it be enough to toggle the stencil on/off multiple times between these draw calls until there is a frame drop?

I would like to enable the stencil only once before issuing multiple draw calls, and disable it after the final one. I would like to change the `stencilOp` and `stencilFunc` somewhere inside of that group of draw calls, but I'm not sure how much there is to be gained from this.

**I'm not asking how to do this with three.js**

*There are a few relatively straightforward ways of doing this with three. Geometries that need to be batched can be put in their own scene and stencil state can be set before and after rendering it. Another one would be to manually sort everything and make the stencil calls only before the first one.*

**My question is, if and why should this queue of commands look different, for any reason?**

What is the difference between having 5, and 255 calls to `gl.enable(STENCIL_TEST)` and `gl.stencilOp()`, is it something that can be ignored or not.

**edit**

I've reduced the number of calls, and achieved the desired effect when rendering opaque objects. However, transparency now became a bit more involved. I am trying to understand what the difference between the 4k and 5k "calls" in `Sceenshot #2` means. Is it something that i should be concerned with at all, or concerned with selectively.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How are you guaranteeing the draw order? Can you put some of the stuff in a separate scene, then turn on stencil, draw scene, turn off stencil, draw other scene or something along those lines? And, is this really a WebGL question? Seems like you're asking how to make three.js behave the way you want it too.

Comment: Yes it's possible to guarantee the render order and it is possible to render it with multiple scenes but it's not really how three expect things to be done. However It's more along the lines of should it even be done and why. I'm interested in what happened with this webgl queue rather than how it happened if that makes sense? It's not a question of "how to do this with three" but rather "should I have my webgl look like this".

Comment: ^ is **happening** (not happened) with the webgl queue ^, i do know exactly what caused it to look like that. Couldn't edit anymore.